# Developer Program for Viewing Passbook-Related Pages

Tags: developer-program, wallet

I have a registered Apple Developer account. However, I cannot view the following pages:

- [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/passtypeids/ios/manage)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/Introduction.html
- https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Passbook

Do I need to join the iOS Developer Program ($99/year) just to view those documentations?

Comment: The last link i.e. Passbook Support Materials seems to be an independent issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4380960?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What sort of registered account do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - those links are pre-release and protected to iOS registered developers. You might get by with an educational account - but most developers use the $99/year plan to gain access to the Provisioning Portal.

Provisioning devices for testing your application on real iPhones rather than the simulator does require a membership, as does any pre-release software or documentation. However, Passbook is not pre-release documentation any more; with the release of iOS 6, they have [published public documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Introduction.html), so you can view this. If you need more information as to what the $99/year membership gives you access to, view their [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) page.